# Link navigation briefly prevented after closing overlaying DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

It seems that some browsers (Chrome, IE) briefly prevent link navigation when a link is clicked immediately after closing an overlaying DOM element.

For example, when you have the following HTML (see https://jsfiddle.net/robbertbrak/emumnjpg/):

```
<a id='my-link' href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Go to Google</a>

<div id="popover-container">
  <div id="popover">Click to close</div>
</div>
```

the following CSS to position the popover container element over the link:

```
#popover-container {
  position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;
}

#popover {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
  position: absolute; left: 200px; top: 200px;
}
```

and the following Javascript:

```
var container = document.getElementById('popover-container');
var link = document.getElementById('my-link');

container.addEventListener('click', function() {
  container.parentNode.removeChild(container);
});

link.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = 'clicked';
  this.parentNode.appendChild(div);
});
```

Reproduce as follows:

- Click twice in quick succession (within about a second) on the link.
- The word 'clicked' appears below the link.
- The browser does *not* open a new tab to navigate to the URL that the link points to.

Note that the link navigation works as expected when there is enough time between clicks.

Also note that the click handler on the link fires as expected, it's just the link navigation that is prevented.

My question: why does this behaviour occur? Is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the second click is coming through as a 'double click' and chrome is ignoring it. You can work around it with this:

```
link.addEventListener('dblclick', function(ev) {
  link.click();
});
```

Watch out for the second fake'ed click on the click handler though.

https://jsfiddle.net/539hr864/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just give your `popover-container`  a `background-color` like orange: https://jsfiddle.net/emumnjpg/1/

Then you will see that the first click just removes the `popover-container` which overlays your link. This is why you just think you click on the link but actually you click on the `popoer-container` on the first click.

Or have a look at this second example where the `popover-container` gets set away from the top so you can click on the link and it works on the first time as expected https://jsfiddle.net/emumnjpg/2/

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I know that the `popover-container` is initially covering the link; this is a necessary part of the setup that triggers the behaviour I'm asking about.